# metodo que verifica se tem algum registro na minha base de dados

Tags: java

Bom dia pessoal. Sou novo em programação Java, e gostaria de um auxílio. Bom, é o seguinte, quero fazer um metodo e verificar se tem algum registro na minha tabela, caso tenha, prossiga com a ação, senão cai fora do if. Eu ja tenho esse select pronto, agora só preciso implementar isso no meu metodo e fazer a verificação.

Aqui esta a classe na qual faz a verificação:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    AcknowledgementsTemporaryFacade ack = new AcknowledgementsTemporaryFacade();
    try {

        if(ack.selectTemporary()){
            System.out.println("Tem registros");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Não tem registros");
        }
```

Logo abaixo é a minha facade, onde eu estou com problema, não sei que tipo de retorno tem que ser esse metodo.. eu coloquei boolean, mais não está dando certo:

```
  public boolean selectTemporary() throws ServiceException {

    try {
       acknowledgementsDao = new AcknowledgementsTemporaryDao();
       if(acknowledgementsDao.selectAckTemporary2());
            return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

E aqui é a o meu select, onde busca na minha base os registros.

```
  public AcknowledgementsTemporary selectAckTemporary2() throws ServiceException {

    AcknowledgementsTemporary ack = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    String commandSQL = "SELECT \"ds_code\", \"it_date_time_ack\" "
    + "FROM \"tb_ack_temporary\" ";

    try {
    openConnection();
    conn = this.conn;
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(commandSQL);

    rs = ps.executeQuery();


    if(rs.next()){
        ack = new AcknowledgementsTemporary();
        ack.setCode(rs.getString("ds_code"));
        ack.setDateTimeAck(rs.getLong("it_date_time_ack"));
        return ack;
    };


    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
      LOGGER.error("command sql: " + commandSQL + "parameters: " + ack.getCode() +    ack.getDateTimeAck());
    } finally {
    ConnectionDatabaseFactory.closeConnection(conn, ps);
    }

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu método **acknowledgementsDao.selectAckTemporary2()** retorna um objeto **AcknowledgementsTemporary** quado encontra um resultado e **null** quando não encontra, logo este método não pode ser utilizado sozinho dentro do if, pois não retorna um boolean.

Para resolver o problema:

- Substitua a linha **if(acknowledgementsDao.selectAckTemporary2());** por
- **if(acknowledgementsDao.selectAckTemporary2() != null)**

Observe também que você está encerrando o **if** ao utilizar o **(;)** no fim da linha, dando fim a esta verificação antes de chegar no **return**.  por este motivo é recomentado utilizar as chaves para abrir e fechar o **if**.

Resumindo o seu código fica como o abaixo

```
public boolean selectTemporary() throws ServiceException {

    try {
        acknowledgementsDao = new AcknowledgementsTemporaryDao();

        if(acknowledgementsDao.selectAckTemporary2() != null){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```